# Safe React Login

Tags: reactjs, authentication

I'm trying to understand how to implement a safe login in react.
I googled a lot and it seems that everyone use the [privateRoute](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/auth-workflow) concept.
In my opinion, it's not safe.

So, here I am asking: what is the safest way to implement a login with react in 2018?
Thank you.

Comment: It's easy for someone with React Router knowledge to fake that they are logged in on the browser side, but they still won't be able to get protected data from your server. So unless you have some sensitive data directly in your JavaScript file, which you shouldn't, it will not be an issue.

Comment: Best way to protect your application is to use sessions or tokenization.

Comment: I agree with that. But what about performance? Why should I gave the whole application to the client instead of giving only the allowed parts?

If I have a big application it is an issue.